# Distribution of distinct balls in identical boxes

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers, balls-in-bins

how can I derive a formula for the number of distributions of $n$ *different* balls in $k$ *identical* boxes. Where $\mathbf{empty\ box}$ is allowed.

I know this is equivalent to finding the number of ways to partition a set of $n$ labelled (distinct) objects into $k\ \mathbf{non\ empty}$ unlabelled subsets, which is basically ${n\brace k}$ ([stirling number of the $2^{nd}$ kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)).

But the problem is, ${n\brace k}$ doesn't allow $\mathbf{empty}$ partitions, where as my problems does.

Comment: Isn't it just $k^n$?

Comment: Is it? I thought $k^n$ would be the case had those boxes been distinct.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I overlooked that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you'll find it's
$$
\sum_{m=1}^k {n\brace m}
$$
Note that I am taking ${n\brace m}=0$ when $m>n$.

Why? How many ways can you fill $m$ identical boxes with $n$ distinct balls such that each box has at least one ball? Now, clearly there must be some number of boxes filled, let that be $m$. $m$ can be anything from 1 to $k$, but if $k>n$, then obviously you can't fill all the boxes, and thus no combination requiring filling of all boxes matters.